# Ok to use PSM to create treatment groups and then plug into CausalImpact?

Tags: time-series, causality, propensity-scores, causalimpact

Is it ok to use propensity score matching to create treatment and control groups and then plug these two time series into CausalImpact to estimate your treatment effect? I might want to do this, for example, if I had many covariates I could potentially match on and no obvious time series (eg different markets) to include as controls in my model. However, I haven't been able to find any examples of people taking this approach.

Comment: What is "causalimpact"?